# Use a variable as ether amount in a require function

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

Here is what I have:

```
require(msg.value > .01 ether, 'Minimum amount required not met');
```

the code above works fine but I want to do is use a variable amount of ether each time, depending on contract,
let's say we have a variable called `ufixed public minimum_ammount` initiated in the constructor that I want to use like this:

```
require(msg.value > minimum_amount ether, 'Minimum amount required not met');
```

can't find a way to do so, any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Well writting `ether` is basically the same thing of writting `10**18`, at least I don't see any difference for now. So, instead of `minimum_amount ether`, you can do `minimum_amount * 10**18,`

Answer (score 0):

I think the `ether` keyword can be used only with constant values: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.4.21/units-and-global-variables.html

If you want to use a variable value, you should provide it in wei (1 ether is 10^18 wei).